# How to execute a script or a funciton through python setuptoos?

Tags: python, pip, setuptools

I use [Distutils](https://docs.python.org/2.7/distutils/introduction.html)  to distribute my package, it's very convinient. Now I want to execute a script or a function after the user installed my package through command like `pip install mypackage`. I thought I could find a API like `register(funtionCalledAfterPackageInstalled)`, just like `atexit.register(someFunction)`, which was often used in python to execute a function before the app exited, but I failed. So I want to ask: is there any elegent way to do such a thing?

**Background**: I reference a frequently updated dll in my package, and I don't want to put it in my pakcage so I don't need to care about the update. I just want it to be automatically downloaded through a function call after my user install my package. And the environment is WINDOWS, so linux pakcage management tools not work.

Comment: After calling `setup()` in your `setup.py` you can execute other Python functions / methods. So here you can run Python program or system call (with subprocess by example).

Comment: @Arount Wow, great, that's what I need. Thank you.

Comment: So I will make proper anwser, maybe it will help other ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After calling `setup()` in your `setup.py` file you can call another Python function or method. So you can run python function making what you need or execute external command with `subprocess` by example.

It will result something like:

```
from distutil.core import setup
import subprocess

setup( ... stuff ...)

# Call external command    
subprocess.Popen('command here', ... attrs ...)
# Or another Python function you wrote
my_function()
```